# possible to disable the Power key on Mac when it's turned on?

Tags: macos, mac, power

I'm looking to be able to disable the power key on my mac after it's been turned on. I've damaged my logic board and when the button gets pressed it crashes my mac... (can elaborate if anyone is interested)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to [disable power button sleep](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20140305140635280)?

Comment: I would like to have the power button fully disabled so it does nothing. ever.